# Layered Navigation in the CMS Wrong Filters

Tags: blocks, cms, layered-navigation, product-list

I tried this method here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241181/cms-page-with-layered-navigation-not-working and successfully added the product listing and layered navigation in the CMS. However, the layered navigation seems wrong (ie., product counts are not correct).

```
<reference name="left">
            <!-- Layered Navigation Block -->
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
                <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>1302</category_id></action>
                <action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
            </block>
        </reference>

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_listing" template="acidgreen/b2b/catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <!-- Product List View -->
                <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>1302</category_id></action>
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Root category should not be used as the category ID but rather its sub-category.